# Concept for an "Order" of Exponents

Tags: abstract-algebra

Given a set $S$ of abstract mathematical objects, let's say that every element $A\in S$ has order 1, denoted $Ord(A)=1$. I then define that for any 2 elements $A$ and $B$ in $S$, $Ord(A\cdot B) = Ord(A)+Ord(B)$ [Note: $A\cdot B$ is not in $S$].

To make this more clear I'll give an example. Let's say $S=\{R,G,B\}$. By definition, we have that $Ord(R)=Ord(G)=Ord(B)=1$. And by the second equation we have that
$$Ord(R^2)=Ord(R\cdot G)=Ord(\frac{R^2\cdot B}G)=2$$
$$Ord(G^3)=Ord(R\cdot G\cdot B)=Ord(\frac{R\cdot G^4}{B^2})=3$$

And so on. So essentially, the Order of a given product is the sum of the exponents of the elements of $S$.

My question is, is there a concept in mathematics that describes this sort of Order?

Much appreciated.

Comment: There is a notion called graded ring.  You might want to read about it.  What you are calling "order" is called "degree".  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graded_ring

Comment: What are exactly $S$ and $\cdot$? The sentence "$A\cdot B$ need not be in $S$" confuses me. 

You need a set of elements of degree $1$ (I guess it is what you intend $S$ to be) with the property that if $A$ and $B$ are in $S$, then $AB$ is not in $S$ (otherwise, if $C=AB$ is also in $S$, what would be the degree of $C^2=A^2B^2$? $2$ or $4$?).

Comment: You're right, I should've written "$A\cdot B$ is not in $S$". Does it make sense now?

Comment: This is just an additive group homomorphism from the free abelian group on a set $S$ to $\Bbb Z$, pretty pedestrian. Or it could also be a homomorphism from the (not abelian) free goup on $S$ to $\Bbb Z$.